dealing with long titles
I create a variable \theme that contains the theme of a document. However, sometimes it can be a bit long (for e.g. like in MWE). My theme appears in a header where it is written using a smaller size and in the head of the first page where the font size is chosen to be a bit larger. This, however, creates a problem as words in my theme break:

Is there any way to manually change the formatting in this one line? If I add \\ in \newcommand{\theme}{my favourite track is \\ Discombobulate} my header breaks as such:

Where I want it to look like this:

How do I do that? Here's my MWE:
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=25mm}
\geometry{left=20mm}
\geometry{right=20mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\theme}{my favourite track is Discombobulate}

\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\large \theme}
\fancyfoot[R]{\large\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}

    {\Huge \theme}

    
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}


Is needed \Huge? If you try \huge?

The easiest way would be two separate commands: \theme and \themeForHeader.  You could even arrange things so that you would say \setTheme[ForHeader]{ForTitle}.  Would that work?

@juanuni, unfortunately it has to be that big

@Teepeemm I also thought of this idea, but the problem is that the actual structure of my document is much more complex and \theme variable is used many times inside my custom package, so doubling the variable (although it might work) can create some problems. I was wondering if I could somehow parse the \theme variable and delete  \ inside it (like I would do it in usual programming languages)

you should use sectioning commands but the direct answer to the question is probably \fancyhead[L]{\large\let\\\relax \theme}

Off-topic: \geometry{a4paper} \geometry{top=25mm \geometry{bottom=25mm} \geometry{left=20mm} \geometry{right=20mm} may be expressed more succinctly as \geometry{a4paper, vmargin=25mm, hmargin=20mm}.

as @DavidCarlisle said in comments, the best solution in this exact situation is to write the theme with \\ and then add \fancyhead[L]{\large\let\\\relax \theme}

I am not sure of you true goals, but remember that when you want to use \\ to   break a sentence, probably you are taking the wrong way.
I guess  that \theme is the title of the document, and then you can use simply \title{\theme}\maketitle for proper formatting, this avoid hyphenation, no matter how long is it. However, the MWE include a commented alternative to do almost the same without using that.
If you want bigger font you can use \Huge inside \title (If that is very elegant is another story) as shown in the MWE.
If you don't want it centered you can use \raggedright, this avoid also the indentation (that have no sense for a title) as shown in the MWE.
If you don't like the default vertical spaces either (unfortunately often people want to be stingy with spacing, but oh well) you can use \vspace* to adjust it as you like (showed in the commented alternative, but you can use also with \maketitle).
Is not clear if you want a header on the title page (that does not appear by default because does not make sense when you already are seeing the huge title) but in that case you can force it with \thispagestyle but using loading fancyhdr after geometry (I left the header  rule in the MWE  to check easily that the text of the corner is really the header).

\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=25mm}
\geometry{left=20mm}
\geometry{right=20mm}
\newcommand{\theme}{\raggedright my favourite track is Discombobulate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\large \theme}
\fancyfoot[R]{\large\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\title{\Huge\theme}
\date{}
\author{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle  % alternative : {\vspace*{1cm}\Huge\theme\par\vspace{2.5cm}}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-7] 
\end{document}

